# Call to undefined method ReflectionClass::register()

Tags: php, exception, reflection

I'm trying to create objects dynamically by its full names (including namespace).

When I write instantiating via `new` keyword - it works fine

```
$coreComponents = ['user' => 'app\web\User'];
$component = coreComponents['user'];
$reflectionClass = new $component();
```

But when I write the code by using *Reflection*:

```
$coreComponents = ['user' => 'app\web\User'];
$component = coreComponents['user'];
$reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($component);
```

it shows me the error:

> Exception: Call to undefined method ReflectionClass::register()

What does it mean? I didn't find any information about `::register()` method, which I do not use.  How to fix it?

P.S. Double backslash didn't work either;

---

I use

```
PHP Version - 7.0.32-0
Ubuntu - 16.04.1
```

Comment: The problem is likely farther down in your code. Is there a `register` method in your component that you try to call?

Comment: Creating an instance of `ReflectionClass` is not the way to new up a class of your own, dynamically. You will have a `ReflectionClass` instance, not the component class. It's very unclear what you're really trying to accomplish here, maybe you need to describe what you're trying to solve with these approaches?

Comment: @jszobody `Is there a register method in your component that you try to call?` --- oh gosh, you're right. I have `ErrorHandler` that extends my `BaseErrorHandler` which is abstract and contains the `register` method

Comment: @jszobody I fixed it. Indeed, I forgot to use `newInstance` / `newInstanceArgs` methods